# Is there a headset made thats completely wireless during gameplay (including XBL chat) for the Xbox One?

Tags: gaming, headset

The Xbox One has been out for almost two years now. Can someone tell me if there's a headset made that's completely wireless (including Xbox Live chat) for the Xbox One? I have searched to no avail in finding one that is 100% wireless during game use.

Answer (score 4):

It's expensive, at $300, but I recommend the [Astro A50](http://www.astrogaming.com/a50-headset/A50-GEN2.html).

[image: Astro A50]

The [manual](https://astro-media.s3.amazonaws.com/manuals/2014/A50_XB1_Manual.pdf) for this headset is online, for you to browse prior to purchase. It includes set up instructions

[image: A50 set up instructions]

The headset has 7.1 surround sound and works on both my Xbox One and PS4. The Astro page says it also works on Xbox 360, PS3 and PC. I haven't tried it on any of those systems. The battery usually lasts about 6.5-7 hours.

I've had no problems with sound or voice quality on the XBox.

Comment: That's actually the one that I have. IMO, it's complete junk because of the stupid wire that's needed for XBL chat. I've had it for almost a year. Bought it directly from Astro for $344. Two months ago, I started getting a ton of static, so purchased a new wire from them for $46.22 (which included tax and shipping). Now I'm getting static again. So ridiculous that I spent almost $400 and now I have something I can't even use. Was hoping to find something else to replace the A50 with one that didn't need _any_ wires.

Comment: I haven't had that experience at all. I've been pleased with mine.